# issue with dup2() and pipe(): using same pipe as stdin and stdout

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, pipe

(this is my first time using stack overflow, so i may have some issues writing)

I am trying to make linux pipe system in c by pipe() and dup2().
i was thinking to redirect stdout of the previous command to stdin of the current command.
when i use a single pipe(ex: ls | cat), the output seems to work well
but the command does not terminate and i cant get any new inputs.
also, it doesn't work at all when i try to use 2 or more pipes.

```cpp
    while(1){ //get command line until quit
        //input command line and parse
        ...

        int fd[2];
        if(pipe(fd) < 0) exit(1);

        //excute commands by seperated by pipes(exArg)
        int start = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < inputLen; i++){    
            //parse command
            
            

            if ((pid = fork()) == 0){
                //redirection
 
                //pipelining(problem in this part)
                if(i > 0) {
                    dup2(fd[0], 0);
                }
                if(i < inputLen - 1) {
                    dup2(fd[1], 1);
                }

                //excute by command type
                if(cmdtype == 1){
                     char path[100];
                     sprintf(path, "/bin/%s", exArg[0]);
                     execv(path, exArg);
                }
            }
            else wait(0);
            //close files
            start = inputs[i] + 1;
        }
        free(cmd);
    }
```

tried closing pipes and re-open it, but didn't work.

Comment: Your code doesn´t handle more than one pipe because there is only one pipe in there, `int fd[2];`. Also, your shell should close both fds *before* waiting for children, and each child should close the fd it isn't using.

Comment: after using mulitple pipes im now getting a bad file descripter error

Comment: I cannot debug invisible code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: this is my minimal problem code. thank you for helping me! https://pastebin.com/h5v0r7ig

Comment: You should post your [mre] here as a text, not as a link to an external resource. Anyway if you want someone to debug your code, you could just as well find a working example on the internet and learn from it. Tere are tons out there, including on this site.

Comment: i posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77521919/using-pipe-between-for-loops-iterations you may check this one. thanks