# using pipe between for loop's iterations

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MAXLEN 512
 
int main()
{
    int pid;
    int fd[1024][2];
    int cmd_idx = 0;
    int cmd_len = 2;
    char* arg1[] = {"ls", NULL};
    char* arg2[] = {"grep", "aa", NULL}; // assume aa.txt aa1.txt in current directory
 
    for (int cmd_idx = 0; cmd_idx < cmd_len; cmd_idx++){
        if(cmd_idx < cmd_len - 1) {
            if(pipe(fd[cmd_idx]) < 0) exit(1);
        }
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0){
            //pipelining
            if(cmd_idx > 0){ //if not the first command, get input from previous pipe output
                dup2(fd[cmd_idx - 1][1], 0);
            }
            if(cmd_idx < cmd_len - 1) { // if not the last command, output to current pipe
                close(fd[cmd_idx][0]);
                dup2(fd[cmd_idx][1], 1);
            }
 
            char path[100];
            if(cmd_idx == 0){
                sprintf(path, "/bin/%s", arg1[0]);
                execv(path, arg2);
            }
            else{
                sprintf(path, "/bin/%s", arg2[0]);
                execv(path, arg2);
            }
        }
        else wait(0);
        if(cmd_idx > 0) close(fd[cmd_idx - 1][1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my program which implements pipe for Linux shell commands.

When I tried using a singe pipe with `dup2()`, it only worked for a single pipe. So I tried using an array pipe `int fd[1024][2]`, but now I'm having a bad file descriptor error.

Can I get an example of using pipe between for loop's iterations?

Comment: Post the actual code that gives the error, not just a random part of it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h5v0r7ig this is the minimal code for simulating, thanks

Comment: @Gamja - "Post the code" meant "Post the code here".  :-)  You can edit the question to add more info.

Comment: Your code obviously cannot handle more than one two commands and one pipe, please remove everything that distracts from this fact.

Comment: how can i get more than one pipe?

Comment: There are many questions about how to set up a pipeline in a custom shell.  Note that the first and last (Nth) processes in a pipeline are treated somewhat differently from the 2nd to (N-1)th processes — the first doesn't have a pipe for input, and the last doesn't have a pipe for output.  There are various ways to handle multiple pipes.  You can create them all before launching any child processes, and each child sorts out its plumbing (standard input and output) appropriately (with `dup2()`) and then closes all the pipe file descriptors.  Or you can create pipes as the children are launched.